# Trying to retrieve data from dialogflow chatbot I have created I get a 401 error

Tags: firebase, dialogflow-es

I'm brand new to using dialogflow. I've created a basic chatbot to test getting the response i've created through the api. I have my POST working but the GET is not getting the data I want and gives me a 401 and stops working.

I'm not sure if my code is in the right direction. Researching hasn't been too helpful.

The idea is a user enters the website -- I've created -- and can interact with the chatbot. It's very very basic. I have set up my entities and intents which the agent has been trained and works when I do the demo. I just want to be able to do the same with my website.

I'm using firebase to store users response and agent response.

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyChQLuBa0Owj-Zbnpk8_uMcIYAmFz4dFj8",
    authDomain: "chatbot-53c37.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://chatbot-53c37.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "chatbot-53c37",
    storageBucket: "chatbot-53c37.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "434930699010"
};
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

var database = firebase.database();


// End Firebase Initialize 
===================================================

// Add data to Firebase


var keyWord = "none";

var accessToken = "2d39bfb1417c41a1b31dba35018c1b74"; // Done
var baseUrl = "https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/";

// Stuff we get from the user responding to the chatbot 
=========================
var text; // user's input
var name; // user's name

var lang = '&lang=en'; 
var query = "What time is it?";

var sessionID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000);

var connected = database.ref(".info/connected");


// Get initial message from bot "Hi Whats your name" 
============================================================


$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: baseUrl + "query?v=20150910&e=event_name" + lang + '&query=' + 
    query + '&sessionId=' + sessionID,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
}).done(function(response) {

// console.log(response);
// console.log(response.result.fulfillment.speech);


}).fail(function(err) {

    throw err;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GET and POST queries for Dialogflow require a different type of request:

- GET requires parameters to be URL encoded
- POST requires that parameters be included in the request body

Also, note that you need to have billing enabled for Firebase functions to perform outgoing network requests.

Sources

- https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/query#get_query
- [Cloud Functions for Firebase - Billing account not configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784135/cloud-functions-for-firebase-billing-account-not-configured)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I finally got it to work after a day of research. I just need a POST.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please mark it as correct and/or upvote it.