# Can i connect to mongodb from my express app hosted on firebase dynamic hosting?

Tags: mongodb, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I am trying to connect to mongodb from my express app hosted on firebase dynamic hosting. I simply created an endpoint to save a data on mongodb. This endpoint can be called from localhost(works fine) but fails to load the page on firebase deploy(Error: could not handle the request)

```
const chris = new User({
    name: 'john',
    username: `test`,
    password: `${Date.now()}` 
  });

app.get('/user', (request, response) => {
      chris.save( (err) => {
        if(err) {
            response.send(`error occured`);
        }
        response.send(`${Date.now()}`);
    });
});
```

Comment: Where do you have MongoDB running?

Comment: It is running as a third party service.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What machine is MongoDB running on? If you are trying to run it on Cloud Functions, how did you start it? If it is running in another cloud service, where do you configure the URL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cloud Functions for Firebase - Billing account not configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784135/cloud-functions-for-firebase-billing-account-not-configured)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that there is a restriction to use network calls (Third party service calls) in the free plan. 
**Answer found in [Cloud Functions for Firebase - Billing account not configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784135/cloud-functions-for-firebase-billing-account-not-configure)**d

The restriction is about outbound access - e.g. can your Function request resources from the general internet. Its absolutely fine to use a function to respond to a webhook, or to access Google-internal services such a the Realtime Database.

If you wanted to call a third party web service (for example) you'd need to enable billing.

For the other quotas, take a look at: https://firebase.google.com/pricing/ - as you can see there are limits to the number of invocations (125,000 at time of writing) and CPU and memory (40k cpu-seconds and 40k GB-seconds) in the free tier.