# firebase CLI does not deploy to correct project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am deploying the development and production branches using git source control. The functions have a `.firebaserc` as below

```
$ cat .firebaserc

{
  "projects": {
    "default": "doodlemobileapp-dev"
  }
}
```

`firebase deploy` works fine and deploys to indicated project. But when to production branch I can see that the `.firebasderc` contents changed:

```
$ cat .firebaserc 

{
  "projects": {
    "default": "doodlemobileapp"
  }
}
```

This indicates that it changed the contents perfectly. However, doing a `firebase deploy` still deploys to `doodlemobileapp-dev`  instead of `doodlemobileapp`.

Comment: those givng a downvote care to explain why?

Comment: The issue is probably with the general presentation of the question. It was a bit hard to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't change the `.firebaserc` file manually. Instead use the `firebase use --project` command to switch to a different project. See the [documentation on project aliases](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#managing_project_aliases)

You could also set up separate targets within the same project, with https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/targets. But I must admit I've never used that myself.

Comment: not related. but do u know https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52266714/firebase-hosting-blocking-script-due-to-cors-issue ? u seems very experienced