# How do I call an external REST API after a diagflow has been completed?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I want to fire off a messaging API with payload after a successful dialogflow interaction. My JS is weak and need some assistance. For example, I want to send an SMS after a successful dialog flow interaction using this API end point:

https://developer.wavecell.com/v1/api-documentation/send-sms-single:

https://api.wavecell.com/sms/v1/{subAccountId}/single 
HTTP POST:

{
  "source": "Developer",
  "destination": "+6512345678",
  "clientMessageId": "MyBd00001",
  "text": "Hello World",
  "encoding": "AUTO",
  "scheduled": "2016-11-03T08:24:20.332Z",
  "expiry": "2016-11-03T18:24:20.332Z"
}

How would I write that in Inline Editor(Powered by Cloud Functions for Firebase)?  I don't need a anything fancy ... just to call this API with its payload.

Thanks.  An example code would suffice.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  If so, please show your code.  StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to illustrate the specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: from Firebase you can only hit external services if you have paid account.

Answer (score 0):

Response your intent with fullfilment feature but it needs firebase billable account such as Blaze plan to call an external API . 
Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784135/cloud-functions-for-firebase-billing-account-not-configured) question.