# non-Google MySQL database connection with firebase cloud function

Tags: mysql, firebase, google-cloud-functions

When i try to connect to my MySQL, server sends me an error `Error: connect ETIMEDOUT`

Here is sample code

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const mysqlConfig = {
        connectionLimit: 1,
        host: "remote_host_ip",
        user: "server_user",
        password: "server_pass",
        database: "server_db",
        port: 3306
    };
    mysql.createConnection(mysqlConfig).connect(function (err) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log("Database is connected");
        } else {
            console.log("Database is not connected " + err);
        }
    });
```

I am on firebase blaze(pay as you go) plan.

Comment: Does your MySQL database allow connections from external IP addresses?

Comment: Is your project on a paid plan or on the free/Spark plan? If the latter, then calls to non-Google services are blocked to prevent abuse. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784135/cloud-functions-for-firebase-billing-account-not-configured

Comment: @Chris you are right. My MySQL database does not allow connections from external IP address.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question title already states it, but you are not using GCP Cloud SQL, right?

In that case, there's a **great possibility** of your MySQL server is not reachable from Cloud Functions. Are you sure network connectivity is OK?

Besides, even in Cloud Functions, [it's a good idea to use connection pools](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/sql). Consider using it, it will be something like that:

```
  var config = {
    user: 'root',
    password: 'akdaskdasdaE',
    database: 'database1'
  }
  config.connectionLimit = 10
  config.multipleStatements = true

  // needed in GCP Cloud SQL, but it seems it's not your case
  // config.socketPath = `/cloudsql/__INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME__`

  var connectionPool = mysql.createPool(config)
  connectionPool.on('connection', () => {
      console.log(`[connectionPool] new connection opened`)
  })

  // then you use connectionPool.getConnection(..)
```

Comment: you are correct my MySQL database is not reachable from firebase cloud functions.

Comment: do you mean ur database had a firewall rule ... or is it that firebase cloud functions do not allow out going data connections to another db ?

Comment: as far as I know there is no network restriction from cloud functions to data connections in other dbs/networks/cloud providers, etc

Comment: @mjsunny by the way, if you think that's a correct answer, please accept it! cheers