# Can I use ElasticSearch/Algolia on my spark plan? Or do I need to upgrade?

Tags: firebase

I am a student writing a webapp using Firebase as backend and hosting. The $25/mo is too costly for me. My webapp requires text search functionality.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call a third party web service you need to enable billing (as discussed here:
[Cloud Functions for Firebase - Billing account not configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784135/cloud-functions-for-firebase-billing-account-not-configured))

You could however opt for the [Blaze](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) plan which is billed on a pay-as-you-go basis, instead of the fixed price flame plan. The cost will remain at $0 if you remain within the quotas specified in the spark plan.

You can also set [spending limits and budget alerts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) in case you are afraid of going over budget.