# Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN myWebsiteName.com:443 in Dialogflow

Tags: node.js, firebase, dialogflow-es

I am using DialogFlow chatbot to get user information on my website. I was first trying to get data from a page. This is the code :

```
const https = require('https');

https.get('myWebsiteName.com/apiToGetData', (resp) => {
    let data = '';

    // A chunk of data has been recieved.
    resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
      data += chunk;
    });

    // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
    resp.on('end', () => {
      console.log(JSON.parse(data).explanation);
    });

  }).on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("Error: " + err.message);
  });
```

But when i checked in console, it printed **Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN  myWebsiteName.com:443.**
When I read about it, I got to know that it is a **DNS lookup timed out error**. But I want to know that is it because of my **free version of Firebase and Dialogflow**? If I buy their plans, will the same code work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable Billing on your account to make outbound calls. Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42787576/6763544) to get clarity on the issue.

Comment: As I am using salesIQ bot which I have integrated with my DialogFlow bot. If I have salesIQ bot paid version, will that be okay or will I have to buy DialogFlow account also?